# Mail-app not using Push

Tags: iphone, email, apns

I just bought an iPhone 4S and configured my mail-accounts. But for some reason, the new mail is only pushed when I open my Mail-app. I set the settings for incoming messages to "Push". Any idea how this is possible?

I my former iPhone, an iPhone 3G, did the job excellent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your issue.

1. Open Settings app.
2. Open Mail, Contacts, Calendars
3. Under the Accounts heading, open "Fetch New Data".
4. Be sure that Push is set to on.
5. Open Advanced at the bottom.
6. Under each individual account, make sure that it is set to Push.  If push is not an option, then your email provider does not support push.  The only ones that I am sure of are iCloud, Microsoft Exchange, and Gmail [(if setup as an Exchange account)](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740).

Comment: This is an old kb article, but I think Yahoo is supported as well. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2625

Comment: This was my solution. Fetch was set on manual and my GMail accounts used Fetch, so only when I opened the app, the mail was Fetched! Thanks!